# Configuration tools for multiple monitors for X / Linux

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, x-windows

I have Ubuntu 10.04 running gnome and two monitors.

I am wondering if a can get a better multi-monitor configuration tool. The one I have, gnome-display-properties, has too many problems, including:

When I swapped my monitors over, the narrower (external) one now on the left. There is a width calculation error, such that I have a virtual monitor the width of the wide-monitor on the narrow-monitor and part of the wide monitor. And a virtual narrow-monitor on the remainder of the wide-monitor. Also the visible mouse pointer does is not aligned with the active spot, an x offset of one monitor width.

I would like, in approximate order of importance:

- nobugs.
- to be able to select which is primary monitor.
- to have multiple configurations.
- configurations to be automatically selected based on which monitors are attached.
- configurations to be cycled (reliably) when display mode key is pressed.
- when a display is deactivated, for windows to migrate to remaining monitors.
- option to not change display resolution when mirroring, but to use side/top blanking bars to pad out screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `nvidia` card, there's an `nvidia-settings` GUI that helps a lot. There's a lot of fairly clear documentation on how to write your `xorg.conf` to take advantage of all the nVidia's `Xinerama` extensions for handling multi-monitors setups.

Comment: no its not got an nvidia.

Comment: ok, sorry. I'll leave the answer here for future reference.